# Por qué me titila el texto cuando corro mi juego?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estoy armando un juego en Python con el framework Pygame, y me viene pasando hace muchos dias que no encuentro la solucion a que el texto con el marcador de puntos y de niveles, titile. Paso el codigo de como tengo el texto.

```
def texto(self, superficie, txt, tamaño, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", tamaño)
    text_surface = font.render(txt, True, blanco)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    superficie.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Despues, a al hora de llamar a esta funcion, estos son los parámetros que le pongo:

```
  self.texto(self.ventana, str(self.puntaje), 20, self.ventana_x // 2, 10)
```

Y dejo también el bucle principal:

```
self.generacion_meteoros(self.vueltas)
    while not self.process_events():
        self.logica()
        self.ventana.blit(self.fondo, [0, 0])
        self.juego_terminado(self.ventana)
        if self.game_over == False:
            self.texto(self.ventana, str(self.puntaje), 20, self.ventana_x // 2, 10)
            self.texto(self.ventana, str(self.vueltas), 20, self.ventana_x // 8, 10)
            self.texto(self.ventana, "VUELTAS: ", 20, self.ventana_x // 15, 10)
        self.reloj.tick(60)
    else:
        pygame.quit()
```

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Puedes subir el código o el bucle principal? Podría ser que estés llamando a la función al final del bucle y parpadee por el tiempo que tarda en hacer todas las acciones?, es decir, desde 'supersicie.fill(color)' hasta el donde llamas a texto

Comment: @DanielSánchez ahí lo deje, gracias por avisar que faltaba.

Comment: ¿En donde mas llamas a `pygame.display.update()/flip()` aparte de en self.texto? ¿es en `self.juego_terminado` uno de esos sitios?

Comment: @FJSevilla el update lo pongo en la funcion juego_terminado y antes de que inicie el bucle principal

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, como dijo Dante en su respuesta (por lo que yo entendí) llamaba a `pygame.display.flip()/update()` dentro de un bucle, por lo que, al momento de correr el juego, esa actualizacion se producía una y otra vez mientras el bucle continuara. Por eso la respuesta a esto es sacar `pygame.display.flip()/update()` del bucle y de las funciones que están dentro del mismo para que no se esté actualizando reiteradas veces, haciendo el efecto de parpadeo.

**Si van a usar `pygame.display.flip()/update()`, que sea AL FINAL del bucle.
Muchas gracias a todos!**

Answer (score 0):

La causa concreta por la que se produce el "efecto de parpadeo" se debe a la secuencia:

1. *blit* del fondo
2. Llamada a `display.update()` en `self.juego_terminado()`
3. Llamada a `display.update()` en `self.texto()`

**El fondo solapa la zona donde el texto es dibujado**, y esta es la clave. Cuando realizas el *update* en `self.juego_terminado()` se dibuja el fondo solapando el texto dibujado en la iteración del ciclo anterior, dejando por unos momentos la pantalla sin mostrar el texto hasta que los *updates* de las llamadas a `self.texto` se producen. Estos milisegundos que pasan entre las llamadas son suficientes para producir el parpadeo. Simplificando tu ejemplo, podemos verlo en:

```
import pygame


BLANCO = 255, 255, 255

pygame.init()
ventana_x, ventana_y = 900, 725
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ventana_x, ventana_y))
# https://opengameart.org/content/pyramid-background
fondo = pygame.image.load('pyramid.jpg')


def texto(superficie, txt, tamaño, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("serif", tamaño)
    text_surface = font.render(txt, True, BLANCO)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    superficie.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    ventana.blit(fondo, [0, 0])                          # << 1
    pygame.display.update()                              # << 2
    texto(ventana, "123456789", 40, ventana_x // 2, 10)  # << 3
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resto de *updates* no causan este efecto siempre y cuando no se produzca un redibujado de la misma zona de la pantalla ocupada por el texto. No obstante, para evitar estos problemas y por eficiencia (`pygame.display.update()`/`flip()` es costosa), lo normal es llamar a la función una única vez al final del ciclo principal cuando tenemos el frame totalmente compuesto. Obviamente puede haber excepciones, especialmente cuando se usa `update` con su verdadero potencial y no como sinónimo de `flip`, con argumentos, permitiendo actualizar regiones concretas de la pantalla en vez de toda ella.